# Breakpoints not hit when debugging SPFx Field Customizer in VSCode

Tags: sharepoint-online, vscode-debugger, spfx, spfx-extension

When debugging a SPFX **Field Customizer** Solution using VS Code, I cannot get the breakpoints to hit in the IDE. If I open the dev tools in the browser, I am able to put in breakpoints in the code and get them to hit, but not in the VSCode IDE.

In contrast, when I debug a **WebPart** using the hosted workbench, I am able to get the breakpoints to hit correctly in the VS Code IDE.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Create Simple Hello World Field Customizer from the MS guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer).
2. Create the test list in my tenant.
3. run gulp serve --nobrowser
4. Put a breakpoint in the render method and then
   start debug from VSCode using the following config:
   {
   "name": "FieldCustomizer debug",
   "type": "chrome",
   "request": "launch",
   "url": "https://testtenant.sharepoint.com/Lists/Orders/AllItems.aspx?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js&fieldCustomizers={"Percent":{"id":"myGUID","properties":{"prop1":"val1"}}}",
   "webRoot": "",
   "sourceMaps": true,
   "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
   "${workspaceFolder}/**",
   "!**/node_modules/**"
   ],
   "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
   "webpack:///../../../src/*": "/src/*",
   "webpack:///../../../../src/*": "/src/*",
   "webpack:///../../../../../src/*": "/src/*"
   },
   "runtimeArgs": [
   "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
   ]
   }

Breakpoint is not hit but field customizer correctly renders in a new instance of chrome after allowing loading of scripts. Same issue in Edge.